# Just started learning Python, explain this for me please

Tags: python-3.x

I had a question on an assignment that I guessed correctly but would like it if someone could explain the reasoning for the answer I chose was correct.

What does the following Python code print out?

```
def addtwo(a, b):
    added = a + b
    return a

x = addtwo(2, 7)
print(x)
```

Answer was 2

Comment: What's your understanding of it and what specifically about it are you asking about?

Comment: After you've asked this and I looked over it again I'm now seeing the definition was to return the 'a' parameter and not the added portion of it. So when the x variable was invoked it returned the variable in 'a'.

Comment: That's pretty much it. Good job.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the mundane question.